# Timer Interval not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to run a pop up script using timer interval and for whatever reason the timer doesnt count it just fires on load.

```
idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $limit = 5;

    if ($.cookie('newVisit') != '1') {
        $.get('/pop_form.htm', function(data) {
            $('.subs-popup').html(data);
        });

        function timerIncrement() {
            idleTime++;
            if (idleTime > $limit) {
                $('.subs-popup ').show();
                idleTime = 0;
            }
        }

        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

        $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function(e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });

        $.cookie('newVisit', '1', {
            expires: 364,
            path: "/"
        });
    }
});
```

Just not really sure what else to do in order to get this to work correctly?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update***

So I did what you said and here is my code with the changes. Except now i am getting an unexpected token error.

```
 var idleTime = 0;
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var limit = 7;

if ($.cookie('newVisit') !='1') {
    $.get('/pop_form.htm', function(data) {
        $('.subs-popup').html(data);
    });
    function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime++;
    if (idleTime > limit) {
        $('.subs-popup ').show();
        idleTime = 0;
    }
   }

    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });

    $.cookie('newVisit', '1', { expires: 364 , path: "/" });
}
});  <----- this is where i get the unexpected token error
```

Comment: Well are you sure it is the fact you do not hide the element to start?

Comment: Your popup may never show if your mouse keeps moving.  The mousemove event keeps setting it back to 0 and you will only show the popup after 5 seconds.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
var timeout = null;

function resetTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timeout)
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                           clearTimeout(timeout)
                           alert("Idle!")
            }, 5000);
}

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    resetTimer();
});
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    resetTimer()
});
```

This uses the return value from `setTimeout()` which is a reference to the timeout.  You can call `clearTimeout()` with this reference and it will cancel/clear/remove the timeout, so you can start a new one each time the mouse moves / a key is pressed - rather than keep a record of how many times it's been hit.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ewzr4sx/

Comment: It's not alternative it's only solution;

Comment: I must have a conflict becuase niether of these solutions are working.  I have no idea i am about to just scrap this whole pop up idea.  I have no idea who to do this like on other website all i want to do is present a subscribe pop up after the person has had a chance to look around and if they close it it goes away for year.  I was using the JS Cookie to drop a cookie but I dont code JS I do php so maybe that will be the way i have to go.

Comment: Take your time.   Open a fresh browser and try the fiddle on its own (move the mouse in the bottom right panel then stop moving and wait)  If that works then try to remove all your code and bring in small parts at a time until it stops working.

Comment: OK new found issue Sorry all I am really not trying to kill you guys with this.  So I made a clean doc with nothing from our main site in it.  It is a simple html doc with a h1 and a p tag.  I added in my subs call and added the proper scripts to the site in the order i believe they are suppose to be in. I have added them into the head not the footer.  It sets the cookie fine and displays the pop up imeadiatly.  The timer doesnt server any function at this time.  Wondering if maybe some of the script calls should be at the footer rather than in the head?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.
Reduced test case:

```js
var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var limit = 5;

 function timerIncrement() {
  idleTime++;
  if (idleTime > limit) {
   alert('Idle!');
   idleTime = 0;
  }
 }

 var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

 $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
  idleTime = 0;
 });
 $(this).keypress(function(e) {
  idleTime = 0;
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**PS:**

- Make sure to declare all your variables with `var`.
- You also should not let your variable begin with `$` if they don't hold a jQuery-Object (e.g. `$limit` should be `limit`)
- Note that
  touch-device users wont move any mouse, thus "idle" every time.
- Be aware that the interval set with `setInterval()` ist not guaranteed to be executed in exactly this time. E.g. browsers with throttle intervals when tab is in background.

Answer (score 0):

After first run you won't see any popup this is because of the scope of the `setInterval()` when it runs 2nd time it runs function in window scope same you can see by

```
function timerIncrement() {
  console.log('scope is:', this);
  idleTime++;
  /* rest your function code goes here... */
```

So to prevent it you have to define `timerIncrement()` in global scope so that `setInterval` can access and call it; :)

Updated code:

```
function timerIncrement() {
  idleTime++;
  if (idleTime > $limit) {
    $('.subs-popup ').show();
      idleTime = 0;
  }
}

var idleTime = 0;
var idleInterval = 0;
var $limit = 5;

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie('newVisit') != '1') {
    $.get('/pop_form.htm', function(data) {
        $('.subs-popup').html(data);
    });

    idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });

    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });

    $.cookie('newVisit', '1', {
        expires: 364,
        path: "/"
    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: OK new found issue Sorry all I am really not trying to kill you guys with this.  So I made a clean doc with nothing from our main site in it.  It is a simple html doc with a h1 and a p tag.  I added in my subs call and added the proper scripts to the site in the order i believe they are suppose to be in. I have added them into the head not the footer.  It sets the cookie fine and displays the pop up imeadiatly.  The timer doesnt server any function at this time.  Wondering if maybe some of the script calls should be at the footer rather than in the head?